# Do we want questions to be migrated from SO to DBA while in beta?

Tags: discussion, support

After the beta we surely want suitable questions to be migrated, but how works the procedure while we are still in beta?

We can

- repost this question on mSO
- add a comment to a question that it
  is suited for dba
- flag suited questions for migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to migrate questions to a site that is in beta, so no.

Comment: Is that private AND public beta? Why can't we migrate questions while it is in public beta? Can diamond mods migrate them?

Comment: @drach it is seriously frowned upon to migrate questions to a site in public beta. This should only be done in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: ~ Things I did not know. One day I hope to catch you in chat _and_ remember to ask you why that's frowned upon if it helps to reinforce the sort of questions that are wanted on the site. Now is not necessarily the time for you to enlighten me. I can wait, I assure you ;) (PS: already asking in chat atm to save you the headache of myself ;p )

Comment: @drachenstern : if they had migrated questions to AI, when it folded, someone would've had to migrate it all back out.  So until they're sure it can stand on its own, it makes sense.

Comment: @Joe ~ So I was enlightened earlier today ;) ... I have my ideas about how that could be resolved in the future, but I'm obviously not an SOIS dev, and I don't know _all_ the paths of their code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think that it is important to get things organized during the beta and moving questions over helps define this site as well as SO.

Answer (score 1):

Beta is a time to allow the site to determine its own future and fate.  It has to develop a strong "taste" for good and bad questions without input from other sites.

Once the migration flood gate is opened, a weak community may end up being defined by outsiders.